# include third party asm libraries into inline assembler c code

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I want to include a *.inc file to my inline assembler in c. How can i make this work?

I'm currently programming with gcc on a raspi with codeblocks.

so anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot work.

Inline assembly code is processed by the compiler. While include files are included into the source file by the preprocessor. This is done before the compiler gets the source file. The preprocessor interprets the inline assembler code as a string literal and will ignore its content.

Also check the [ARM GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html), chapter "Common pitfalls / Preprocessor macros".